# How to boot from USB on i-life zedbook tablet

Tags: boot, usb, bios, tablet

I want to install win10 via usb but when I enter bios, there is no option to boot from usb. I have successfully tested my memory stick on other PC's.

[image: Bios pic 1]

[image: Bios pic 2]

Comment: Can you specify in your question what is the manufacturer and the model of your tablet?

Comment: I-life ZEDBOOK 2 in 1 3G http://i-life.us/product/zedbook/

Answer (score 2):

I guess that your Windows OS image was not mounted properly (specifically for UEFI) on the memory stick. You might want to repeat the mounting procedure once again using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/).

In the Rufus interface make sure that you choose the following settings:

1. Device: [Your USB memory stick name]
2. Partition scheme and target system type: GPT partition scheme for UEFI computer
3. File system: FAT32
4. You can leave the default values for *cluster size* and *new volume label*
5. Check *quick format*
6. Check *create bootable disk using ISO image* and choose the location of your ISO image

This should do the trick, more info [here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html).

If it does not work then you can try one of the methods suggested on [Microsoft forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/unlocking-the-hidden-insydeh20-bios-settings-with/b824ac2c-e631-4d9b-80b5-6e01b8accc71?auth=1). It says that you need to be able to switch to legacy boot.

These were the steps mentioned:

1. Set a supervisor password
2. Disable secure boot
3. Restart your machine
4. Clear the supervisor password
5. Boot from your USB memory stick

**DISCLAIMER:**

The manufacturer of your laptop (tablet?) on their offical webpage advises [not to update to Windows 10](http://i-life.us/product/zedbook/#tab-faq). I also do not seem to find any drivers for this particular device, what might be a problem after the Windows 10 clean install, as your chipset or wi-fi modem or something else might not work properly.

Comment: thats right bro, i did what you say now its wirks. thx a lot.

Comment: Great to hear that I was able to help you! Please accept my answer. Here is the guide on how to accept an answer - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/319051.