# Boot Failure in ZEDNote 14i

Tags: operating-systems

I have recently purchased I-life ZEDNOTE 14I 12v laptop with windows 10 pre installed os but accidently my drive is formatted and I have lost my all data including OS. Later on I have tried to boot my laptop but It shows no bootable device detected error message. So need help to install windows os on my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you can't without the original installation disk or without purchasing Windows 10.

First, go back to where you bought it, embarrassing as it might be, and ask for help. The vendor might provide service for free or a low fee to keep a customer.

Second, If you have purchase receipts, contact the manufacturer and try to get the OEM installation media.

Finally, if that doesn't work, and you don't wish to buy a new copy of Windows 10 (Home is ~US$100), you can install another OS such as Linux. Ubuntu, for example, will partituion the disk as needed. There are [directions for booting from USB](https://superuser.com/questions/1126226/how-to-boot-from-usb-on-i-life-zedbook-tablet).